# How to write an if statement to check if there is a Applicant ID associated with a User ID in .NET Entity Framevwork MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement, model-view-controller, parameter-passing

I've managed to set up a method in my Account Controller that takes the id associated with a users login and pushes it to my Get_Profile method in another controller.

```
public ActionResult CheckProfile()
    {
        string userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
        return RedirectToAction("GetNAA_Profile2", new { UserId = userId, Controller = "NAAProfile" });
    }
```

The GetNAA_Profile2 method is defined like this within the DAO section of the Data layer.

```
public NAA_Profile GetNAA_Profile2(string UserId)
    {
        IQueryable<NAA_Profile> _profiles;
        _profiles = from profile
                        in _context.NAA_Profile
                    where profile.UserId == UserId
                    select profile;


        return _profiles.ToList<NAA_Profile>().First();

    }
```

It pulls up the associating profile matching up with the UserId from the Profile table in a database I have set up in a database.

```
CREATE TABLE [b].[NAA_Profile] (
[ApplicantId]      INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[ApplicantName]    NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
[ApplicantAddress] NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
[Phone]            NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
[UserId]           NVARCHAR (128) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ApplicantId] ASC)
```

);

The method is then finally executed in the Profile controller returning a view with the passed UserId.

```
 public ActionResult GetNAA_Profile2(string UserId)
    {
        return View(_NAAService.GetNAA_Profile2(UserId));
    }
```

My main question is how can I implement an if statement in my method to check if there is a profile associated with the UserId and then redirect the user to another method if there isn't any matching rows.

Comment: Why aren't you returning the user id with the profile if they rely on each other, if a profile is directly associated with an account.

Comment: Do you mean at the final example of code? I figured you could return a profile by passing the UserId as a parameter for it to check belongs in the table.

Comment: In case there is no associated record your `GetNAA_Profile2` would give an exception. You should consider changing it for `.FirstOrDefault()`. If no record is found it would return `null`

Comment: @bradbury9 Then how would I apply the if statement to check this? `if (UserId = null) { return RedirecToAction ...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change .First() to .FirstOrDefault(). First() will throw an exception if there are no elements in the list.

```
public NAA_Profile GetNAA_Profile2(string UserId)
    {
        IQueryable<NAA_Profile> _profiles;
        _profiles = from profile
                        in _context.NAA_Profile
                    where profile.UserId == UserId
                    select profile;


        return _profiles.ToList<NAA_Profile>().FirstOrDefault();

    }
```

then change action result to below

```
public ActionResult GetNAA_Profile2(string UserId)
    {
        NAA_Profile _profile = _NAAService.GetNAA_Profile2(UserId);
        if(_profile != null) 
        {
           return View("with profile");
        }
        else
        {

          return View("No Profile"); // or any other method you want to redirect to
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You could add an additional method that does the check for you. Something like:

```
public bool HasProfile(string UserId)
{
    IQueryable<NAA_Profile> _profiles;
    _profiles = from profile
                    in _context.NAA_Profile
                where profile.UserId == UserId
                select profile;


    return _profiles.Any();
}
```

You can then call this method from your CheckProfile method:

```
public ActionResult CheckProfile()
{
    string userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

    bool profileExists = HasProfile(userId);
    if(profileExists)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("GetNAA_Profile2", new { UserId = userId, Controller = "NAAProfile" });
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("NoProfile", ...);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why make the method of type `bool` and not of type `NAA_Profile`?

Comment: I guess it depends on if you want to use the NAA_Profile data or not. If you only want to check if something exists a bool is fine and consumes less memory

Comment: Would I need to implement the HasProfile in my IDAO, and Service layers too?

Comment: It needs to be implemented on the layer that the Controller can call (your service layer) and in the layer that can talk to the database (your Data layer). I can't be certain without knowing more about your project.

Comment: Isn't there a simpler way to do it just within the ProfileContoller itself?

Comment: Looking at the original question, it looks like you are redirecting to the ProfileController from the CheckProfile method on the AccountController? I thought you wanted to redirect from AccountController to a different method on ProfileController based on whether the profile exists or not. If that's not the case then you can redirect to the ProfileController and do the check there, but you don't want to redirect the user again as it will get very messy to understand where the user is going to end up.